# 3D mesh plot of 10 node tetrahedron mesh

Tags: python, abaqus

I have an abaqus inp file with nearly a million elements of 10 node(quadratic) tetrahedron mesh. It is a very complicated model. Can you please help me with plotting the 3D volume mesh in python and also map the stress or strain values to the respective elements? I have to plot the mesh and stress/strain values in python because I need to run many iterative simulations with different loading conditions and compare the results.

Thanks in advance

[A small snippet of the inp file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZk7f.png)